# Shopware (5): Which Shopware Version uses which min PHP Version?

Tags: symfony, shopware

Does anybody know which Shopware Versions run which PHP versions?

Something like min/max php version for e.g. Shopware 4.3 or 5.5...

Kind of a list.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just typing your question on google show the system requirement for shopware in the first result..

Comment: Question which I read, and answer I did found where I said I found it. So I don't see your point. (It's all in System Requirements / Hosting)

Comment: So you found a list like my answere below? Or did you just found this for a specific SW-Version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SW-Version   | PHP-Version
Shopware 4.3 | 5.3.2 - 5.6.4
Shopware 5.2 | 5.6.4 - (without ioncube plugins and LicenceManager up to 7.2)
Shopware 5.3 | ≙
Shopware 5.4 | ≙
Shopware 5.5 | 5.6.4 - 7.2 (7.2 recommended)
Shopware 5.6 | 7.2+ (7.3 recommended) !!!7.2.20 and 7.3.7 are not compatible!!!
Shopware 5.7 | 7.4+ (PHP 8 compatible) Older versions are not supported anymore.
Shopware 6.x | ≙
```

Latest Shopware 5 Requirements [DE 5.7](https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-5-de/tutorials-und-faq/systemanforderungen-hosting) | [EN 5.7](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/tutorials-and-faq/system-requirements-hosting)

General Shopware 6 Requirements [DE](https://docs.shopware.com/de/shopware-6-de/erste-schritte/systemvoraussetzungen) | [EN](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/first-steps/system-requirements)

> Replaced `*.*` with `≙` what means: **same as above**

Shopware supported PHP below 5.6.4 untill version 4.3.

After Shopware reached version 5.2 they decided cut the working with ioncube because actually on every php version change they had to wait on ioncube to bring out a new version. So from 5.2 plugins are open source with different license of usage.
You could use later versions of php than 5.6 e.g. 7.0 and so on but only if you have no plugin that is ioncube crypted. Also the Licence Manager has to be removed.

From SW 5.5+ Showare starte to support PHP 7.2

SW 5.6 supports 7.3 as well but some versions of 7.2/7.3 (see list) are not supported.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which part of the question led you to believe this was not a "read the docs" question?

Comment: Because the question was pointed to all different sw versions and its possible php version... Since i'm dealing with SW sind SW4 and went to a lot community days, i know that there are some informations which not can be found in the docs. I don't even know if there are still docs for SW 4. Even if its a SW5 question. But there are still SW4 out there! And of corse you will not find the info that you can run sw5.2 with php 7(depending on plugins) and why sw decided to remove ioncube. May a info that helps to understand :)

Comment: I think the basic Shopware PHP support is way more greater than some plugins does. However, we should devide this into vanilla Shopware usage or Shopware PHP support with plugins. Of course we can't list here all plugins, but we should give the readers the hint, that some plugins may differ the PHP support to the official ones.

Comment: For Shopware 6 it is:
PHP
7.2 or higher (7.2.20 and 7.3.7 are not compatible)

Comment: It says `Shopware 6.x | *.*` what actually means so much like... `Shopware 6.x | as above` but I changed the sign to ≙ and added an explanation as well to make it more clear :) @David

Comment: "they had to wait on ioncube to bring out a new version ... From SW 5.5+ Showare starte to support PHP 7.2" - Ironic then that an ionCube Loader for PHP 7.2 was released in Dec 2017, over 9 months *before* shopware 5.5.0 was released. :)

Comment: May they had one... but i practice it was allways a pain dealing with updating plugins and its ioncube encodings... i'm sure this was a very good decision. And this was the info that was shared on the community day 2018. So probably they developed the 5.5 and there were no ioncube support for 7.2 since coding a shop system is not done in 1 month ^^ guess this took a longer time may that overlapped. And  while developing they decided this.

Comment: You can find compatible versions in each Showpare installation in `<shopware-root-path>/engine/Shopware/Components/Check/Data/System.xml` which is the info that is used in backend under settings => system informations

Comment: true, but it does not show the versions which are not compatible e.g. 7.2.20 and 7.3.7 even if the shopware version supports up to php 7.4.99